# Stop visual studio from reloading swagger UI

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core-webapi, swagger-ui

I have updated my visual studio to version 16.10.2 (enterprise).

Now when I run my Asp.net Core 5 Web API, every time I modify something in my code, visual studio runs a task in the background, and with that, chrome refresh my swagger UI, and all my data get lost.

How can I stop this behavior?

I have always used swagger UI to test my APIs, but this behavior of visual studio is really annoying!

See the video for better understanding: [video](https://www.filemail.com/d/vkeeunjivccyjgf)

Comment: `chrome refresh my swagger UI, and all my data get lost.`could you please show us an example, is it self refresh?

Comment: @JerryCai See the video for better understanding: https://www.filemail.com/d/vkeeunjivccyjgf

Comment: It's not just swagger UI that refreshes every time, actually, all of my projects get a refresh on chrome web saving something. This doesn't happen on edge!

Answer (score 5):

There is an option in visual studio which will refresh chrome every time you save something.
you can disable this behavior by selecting `none`.

Go to: Tools > Options > Projects & Solutions > ASP.NET Core > Auto build and refresh options = and put it to `none`