# When I change the file extension, the page refreshes

Tags: swagger, page-refresh, system.io.file

I use Swagger to test APIs, and when I use the following code to change the file extension, the page refreshes:

`System.IO.File.Move(strFiles.FirstOrDefault(), Path.ChangeExtension(strFiles.FirstOrDefault(), ".html"));`

Thank you

Comment: and not display response

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's a bit late and you've already found a solution but I had exactly the same problem and solved it this way:

Go to: Tools > Options > Projects & Solutions > ASP.NET Core > Auto build and refresh options and put it to **none** (https://stackoverflow.com/a/68143618)